# How to update a ListView from an AsyncTask before it completes

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have a client application that uses sockets and input/output stream to communicate with a server and ask for some data. I've created an AsyncTask and on doInBackground() of it I make the connection and send/receive data.
**doInBackground():**

```java
@Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... objIn) {

            // we create a TCPClient object and
            client = new T_Client(new T_Client.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                // here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(Object objIn) {
                    Log.v(tagTask, "Object Received: " + objIn);                        
                        Log.w(tagTask, "Object returned: " + objIn);
                        mapReturn = (Map<String, Integer>) objIn;
                        Log.i(tagTask, "Map Object Returned: " + mapReturn);
                        onProgressUpdate();                     
                }
            });
            client.run();

            return objIn;
        }
```

User is a simple class to help me process the data I get from the server.
I get a Map from the server as a "Users List",which I want to display in a ListView on my Main Activity, with Username(String) and OnLine status(Integer) and I pass it to a local Map object. Then I call the onProgressUpdate() method of my AsyncTask.
**onProgressUpdate():**

```java
@Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... voids) {
            super.onProgressUpdate();

            for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : mapReturn.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue() == 1) {
                    User user = new User(entry.getKey(), "YES");
                    Log.v(tagTask, "UserName: " + user.getUser());
                    Log.v(tagTask, "Online Status : " + user.getOnLine());
                    listUsers.add(user);
                } else if (entry.getValue() == 0) {
                    User user = new User(entry.getKey(), "NO");
                    Log.v(tagTask, "UserName: " + user.getUser());
                    Log.v(tagTask, "Online Status : " + user.getOnLine());
                    listUsers.add(user);
                }
            }

             mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

In here, I iterate through the Map object's entries and for each entry I create a User object and then add the user object to my ArrayList "listUsers", which is the array list I use for my ListView's adapter. Now when I run the mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() of course I get an error because I'm trying to update my main UI, not from the main UI thread.
The reason that I can't use the onPostExecute() method is because I keep doInBackground() running(client.run()). And the reason I do that is because I have to keep the connection between the server and the client alive so that I can ask for data from the server and the server to send those data.

So I'm asking you guys if there is a way to update my ListView before the AsyncTask completes(which in this case, it'll never get to onPostExecute);

P.S. I've noticed something strange that I can't explain. When I tap on an EditText that I have in my activity, and the keyboard pops up, the ListView updates and I can see my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The reason that I can't use the onPostExecute() method is because I keep doInBackground() running(client.run()).

IMHO, that is an inappropriate use of `AsyncTask`. Do not tie up a resource from a resource pool indefinitely, when you are not the one who create and manage the pool.

Instead, create your own thread. Then use `Handler` to pass messages to code of yours that runs on the main application thread, to update your list.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "when you are not the one who create and manage the pool"?

Comment: @akafortes: `AsyncTask` maintains a thread pool (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern). Normally, you do not create this pool. `AsyncTask` creates it for you. In certain conditions, that pool will have only *one* thread in it. If you tie up that thread indefinitely, you will not be able to use `AsyncTask` for anything else. In this case, you did not create the resource pool, and you are not managing the resource pool, and so you should not tie up a resource from that pool indefinitely.

Comment: OK, so I should create, and keep alive, the connection in a Handler and do all the communication (send the data request, and receive the actual data) using that Handler?
Would you suggest doing it that way, and when I receive an Object then call the AsyncTask to handle it?  
**EDIT:** or even skip the AsyncTask completely?

Comment: @akafortes: "OK, so I should create, and keep alive, the connection in a Handler and do all the communication (send the data request, and receive the actual data) using that Handler?" -- no. You would convert your `AsyncTask` to a `Thread`. Rather than `onProgressUpdate()` or `onPostExecute()`, you send `Message` objects to a `Handler`, where the `Handler`'s `handleMessage()` method would update your UI. See https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html for a slightly overly complex demonstration.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I'll give it a look and will come back to accept the answer if it helps :)